# Get the specific URL from the website link name (using VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, url, hyperlink

Hello I found the below code also here...But this results all links copy into sheet....What if I want only to copy the URL from specific link name? Please help me code. For example with below code...I want the URL from this link name "Getting started with Excel VBA - I Programmer". Should result a URL in cell A1 "http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/automating-excel/1264-getting-started.html"
See the image also...Thanks in advance!!!

```
Sub webpage()

    Dim internet As Object
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String

    Set internet = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    internet.Visible = True

    URL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+program+in+vba"
    internet.Navigate URL

    Do Until internet.ReadyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    Set internetdata = internet.Document
    Set div_result = internetdata.getelementbyid("res")


    Set header_links = div_result.getelementsbytagname("h3")

    For Each h In header_links
        Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
        Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
    Next

    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAmOe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of `innerText` property before adding the URL to the worksheet

```
For Each h In header_links
    If h.innerText = "Getting started with Excel VBA - I Programmer" Then
        Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
        Cells(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = link.href
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Oh it's work...but when i apply to my realy project it doesn't work.  I changed the URL into `URL = "http://iweb.mywork.com/location/place/en-US/OnD/DR/DR%20Form/Pages/default.aspx"`  Got runt-time-error Automation error,  The object invoked has disconnected from its client...when i clicked debug it highlighted in yellow this line --> `Do Until internet.readyState >= 4`...any help please...thanks

Comment: I found the solution for the time-out error...Insted of Do loop..I used while wend....But i have next problem...on the debug mode, the arrow pointing this line -->  Set internetdata = internet.Document...pls help